# Docker-compose, how to create an image that include both backend app + database/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, deployment, mariadb, dockerhub

I'm fairly new to docker-compose and I wanted to create an image of an application that I've built recently.

The only issue that I'm having is that when I run `docker-compose up` locally it works (i.e docker pulled both the MariaDB image from docker hub and built my backend accordingly) I can access it via my browser and bla bla.

Now comes the time to deploy the app on azure and I noticed that it's not building the prebuilt `MariaDB` image. It is only building the backend app causing deployment failure.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3.2'
services:

  db:
    container_name: test-db
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: saicom
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app-network  

  be:
    container_name: test-be
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - '8080:4200'
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    networks:
      - app-network
     

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I tried to comment the be service in the docker-compose.yml file
and it is giving this
[image]

I'm not sure why docker-compose is skipping the MariaDB image and not including it in my app.

I need a good samaritan to explain me what's wrong with my build.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you actually running this setup, such that the database doesn't start?  Compose runs off of YAML files, not PNG-format images; can you [edit] the question so that the configuration is plain text and not an image?

Comment: Done, when I'm saying images I'm referring to DOCKER IMAGE lol not png-format images.

Comment: Can you show us the full logs when you build, please

Comment: The message is fairly clear, the mariaDb container is from a prebuilt image (not a dockerfile that needs building) so it skips it.  You need to include more info about exactly what you are trying to do (end goal) and what you have tried.  You are misunderstanding something about docker/compose so we need to know what you're even trying to do before we can help.